# How to copy files from client system directory to server system directory via remoting

Tags: c#, file-copying

I am copying files from one path to another path in my pc as

```
        string destpath= Application.StartupPath + @"\Multiple Documents1";
        string soucepath= @"D:\Naresh WORK AREA\Naresh\Multiple Documents1";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
         DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(soucepath, destpath+@"\"+filename.doc, true);
```

It works fine in single user inveronment. Now I am using remoting with windows service, I want to save the file into server i'e where my service is running. If I take my source path to the server, it will not identify the sourcepath as the client system path. I know the destination path is service startuppath. But How can I take my source path to service running system.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using local absolute paths you can use UNC paths as in \ComputerName\ShareName. The account your Windows Service is running under of course Needs proper permissions to access the Shares. 
When configuring your service, use the perspective of the server the service is running on. So you need to use a UNC path for the client directory, but you can keep the absolute path on the server side. 
You can set up a new share on the client computer in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I am trying to copy to my server as \CENTAUR-LPTP\D:\testATENEW It is throwing exception as The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: The error is correct; use a Format like \\CENTAUR-LPTP\D$\test\ATENEW. Please note that D$ is a administrative share that might be deactivated and is only accessible for Administrators (on the target Computer CENTAUR...). I strongly recommend not to use the administrative Shares but to create a separate one (e.g. on the Test-Folder) with a permission set that matches the requirements. Your System Administrator can help you if you have questions on how to create and secure a share.

Comment: thank you.. But now it is giving exception as   Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: As I said, the account that your Windows Service runs under must be Admnistrator on the target machine. Please learn how Shares work; this knowledge is essential for solving your problem. Do a search for "Windows how to share files". A link from the MS Homepage: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/share-files-with-someone